# Namespaces packages several levels deep, and sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, namespace-package, sphinx-apidoc

I'm trying to use packages like "project-a" in a namespace like "com.company", with implicit namespaces.

I'm finding that sphinx-apidoc isn't putting my packages in to the toc in the docs, I suspect because both the `com` and `company` namespaces have nothing in them.

sphinx-apidoc is running with `--implicit-namespaces`, from the standard config pyscaffold gives me in a basic project.

I get the following in my sphinx-build output:

```
checking consistency... /Users/nward/Code/scratch/namespaces/project-a/docs/api/com.company.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
```

Any ideas, before I start digging in to the sphinx code?

I've posted the code here - really nothing to it at the moment: https://github.com/nward/com_company_project-a

Answer (score 0):

**I am running into the same issue trying to convert a python package to native namespaces.**

I have been running tests trying to solve this using the native folder from https://github.com/pypa/sample-namespace-packages as per documentation https://packaging.python.org/namespace_packages but with **an extra level** like:

```
setup.py
docs/
example_pkg/
    # No __init__.py here.
    middle_package/
        # No __init__.py here.
        subpackage_a/
            # Sub-packages have __init__.py.
            __init__.py
            module.py
```

the commands to generate the documentation are, first:

```
sphinx-apidoc --implicit-namespaces --force -o docs/ ./example_pkg/
```

then

```
make -C docs html
```

The problem seems to be that the example_pkg.rst does not contain any link to a subpage which is expected:

```
example\_pkg namespace
======================

.. py:module:: example_pkg
```

instead of:

```
example\_pkg namespace
======================

.. py:module:: example_pkg

Subpackages
-----------

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

    example_pkg.subpackage_a
```

When using [pkgutil-style namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#pkgutil-style-namespace-packages) everything does work as a charm though ?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29912379)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @isopach Thanks for your reviewing work here. You are absolutely right that I am not really answering the question here, but it also is not a different question. I ran into exactly the same issue, and just tried to clarify the context, so others have more to go on. Kind regards.